# **wall stud** is more commonly used both in US and UK, so where is the word studwork being used?

Tags: word-usage

This [post](http://www.soundproofing.org/infopages/channel.htm) use studwork to refer to stud

> Resilient channel is a thin metal channel that is intelligently designed to substantially improve the sound insulation of drywall, sheetrock, plasterboard walls and ceilings. The channel effectively isolates drywall from the framing **studwork**, which results in the weakening of sound waves substantially.

while [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud) uses **wall stud**, and this [post](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Stud) uses stud and  **wall stud**.

obviously, **wall stud** is more commonly used both in US and UK, so where is the word studwork being used?

consider following image (img_2)

[image]

the vertical post pointed out by red arrow is a stud, the vertical post pointed out by blue arrow is another stud, the whole thing is A studwork, right?

the following is archived, only for the comments history

Are there 4 studs in the following image (img_1)?

[image]

Comment: They are all used together. Rather than being alternative words for the same things they have different meanings.  You will find them used here for example (where the usage is entirely compatible with Australian English): https://www.carpentry-tips-and-tricks.com/Interior-wall-framing.html

Comment: An individual stud is called just that, a stud.  The entire collection of studs in a wall or an entire building is called the "studwork".

Comment: @JohnFeltz Are there 4 studs in the img_1? The entire collection of all of them  is called the "studwork", right?

Comment: @Lambie consider img_2, where the vertical post pointed out by red arrow is a stud, the vertical post pointed out by blue arrow is another stud, the whole thing is A studwork, right?

Comment: @Lambie Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer?

Answer (score 2):

"studwork" and studs are not the same thing. Each vertical post in the drawing is a stud. Altogether, they form the studwork. It's like frame/framing and framework or bricks and brickwork. The word work is used in construction like that to refer to a whole made of individual things.

- studwork
- formwork [for concrete]
- framework
- brickwork

All those refer to an entire structure and not countable noune (in the grammar sense) as with studs, forms, frames and bricks.

All of the structure created by the studs in the picture. Not just two studs (which you show with your arrows). I don't think I can be any clearer than this.

Example: The studwork for the room was badly done. Two studs were not properly placed.

Brickwork is masonry produced by a bricklayer, using bricks and mortar. Typically, rows of bricks—called courses—[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formwork) are laid on top of one another to build up a structure such as a brick wall.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brickwork)

Formwork is temporary or permanent molds into which concrete or similar materials are poured. In the context of concrete construction, the falsework supports the shuttering molds.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formwork)

work supported, strengthened, held together, or ornamented by studs//
walls … of studwork with lath and plaster
[Merriam Webster - studwork](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/studwork)